# Html.fromHtml rendering issue in android

Tags: android

[image]

I want to show the following html text using TextView in a formatted way.

```
![<BODY Style="font-family: Arial;">Following 3 files have been added to the folder 'A UI UX' in the Project 'A' by B<p> Please use download link to access the file </p><p><table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' border='0'><tr><td> 1. </td><td> &nbsp; &nbsp;1KB -- - Copy (10) - Copy - Copy - Copy - Copy - Copy.txt&nbsp; </td><td> <a href=https://www...><img style='cursor:hand;color:blue;' src='https://www...DownloadFliles.gif'alt='Download Document'/></a></td></tr><tr><td> 2. </td><td> &nbsp; &nbsp;1KB -- - Copy (10) - Copy - Copy - Copy - Copy.txt&nbsp; </td><td> <a href=https://www...><img style='cursor:hand;color:blue;' src='https://www....gif'alt='Download Document'/></a> </td></tr><tr><td> 3. </td><td> &nbsp; &nbsp;1KB -- - Copy (10) - Copy - Copy - Copy.txt&nbsp; </td><td> <a href=https://www....><img style='cursor:hand;color:blue;' src='https://www....gif'alt='Download Document'/></a> </td></tr></table></p></BODY>
I have used this following code to display it in a formatted manner 

Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(msgInfo.getmMsgText());        
mTxtView.setText(htmlSpan);][2]
```

But it is not recognizing the  tag and so not displaying the individual rows in a new line.(Refer to screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

This is the [list of accepted tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html). Your tag doesn't seem to be found there.

Comment: While that list is old, [the source code to the `Html` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) does not show `<table>` either. That is because `TextView` has no table support.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I should have added some copyright comment in my answer :)